# MsSQL query takes too long on CentOS with PHP PDO

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, pdo, centos

We are running MSSQL on CentOS Linux 7 (Core) with PHP 7.1;

```
    $dbh = new PDO ("dblib:version=7.0;charset=UTF-8;host=$mssql_pp_hostname:$mssql_pp_port;dbname=$mssql_pp_dbname","$mssql_pp_user","$mssql_pp_pass");


            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("
                query
            ");

    $stmt->execute();
```

When running a simple query to select 1 item. It takes 0.6~0.9 seconds. Of which about ~0.2 are only spent on the connection.
It takes 0.8 to select a 100 items.

However when connecting form an external client it seems to be running lightning fast. Such as the Microsoft SQL manager tool for Windows.

We are connecting via localhost with PHP. So I am guessing it has to do with some local settings or maybe the driver we are using.

What exactly could be causing this?

Comment: What is the value of your `$mssql_pp_hostname` variable?

Comment: @CvetomirLazarov It's: `$mssql_pp_hostname = 'localhost';`

Comment: Could you try with 127.0.0.1
If it works, I'll post an answer with explanations.

Comment: @CvetomirLazarov Now it's `0.7193s` long. With `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.